# How to define string literal with character type that depends on template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, string-literals

```
template<typename CharType>
class StringTraits {
public:
    static const CharType NULL_CHAR = '\0';
    static constexpr CharType* WHITESPACE_STR = " ";
};

typedef StringTraits<char> AStringTraits;
typedef StringTraits<wchar_t> WStringTraits;
```

I know I could do it with template specialization, but this would require some duplication (by defining string literals with and without `L` prefix).

Is there a simpler way to define const/constexpr char/wchar_t and char*/wchar_t* with same *string literal* in a template class?

Comment: Sorry, what is the problem? What are you trying to do? What is "it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit just edited the description, I want to specify the template parameter to either char or wchar_t. But it can not be compiled for wchar_t.

Comment: For `wchar_t` you should use `L"..."`.

Comment: Does `WHITESPACE_STR ` have to be a string literal? Can't it be a character?

Comment: @StoryTeller this is just a demo, there will be more cases, currently I'm trying to convert a number to it's n-th string representation, there will be 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th'.

Answer (score 18):

There are several ways to do this, depending on the available version of the C++ standard.
If you have C++17 available, you can scroll down to **Method 3**, which is the most elegant solution in my opinion.

**Note:** Methods 1 and 3 assume that the characters of the string literal will be restricted to **7-bit ASCII**. This requires that characters are in the range [0..127] and the [execution character set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) is compatible with 7-bit ASCII (e. g. [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) or [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)). Otherwise the simple casting of `char` values to `wchar_t` used by these methods won't give the correct result.

### Method 1 - aggregate initialization (C++03)

The simplest way is to define an array using aggregate initialization:

```
template<typename CharType>
class StringTraits {
public:
    static const CharType NULL_CHAR = '\0';
    static constexpr CharType WHITESPACE_STR[] = {'a','b','c',0};
};
```

---

### Method 2 - template specialization and macro (C++03)

(Another variant is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52742402/7571258).)

The aggregate initialization method can be cumbersome for long strings. For more comfort, we can use a combination of template specialization and macros:

```
template< typename CharT > constexpr CharT const* NarrowOrWide( char const*, wchar_t const* );
template<> constexpr char const* NarrowOrWide< char >( char const* c, wchar_t const* )       
    { return c; }
template<> constexpr wchar_t const* NarrowOrWide< wchar_t >( char const*, wchar_t const* w ) 
    { return w; }

#define TOWSTRING1(x) L##x
#define TOWSTRING(x) TOWSTRING1(x)  
#define NARROW_OR_WIDE( C, STR ) NarrowOrWide< C >( ( STR ), TOWSTRING( STR ) )
```

**Usage:**

```
template<typename CharType>
class StringTraits {
public:
    static constexpr CharType const* WHITESPACE_STR = NARROW_OR_WIDE( CharType, " " );
};
```

[**Live Demo at Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/696522212d9905ee)

**Explanation:**

The template function `NarrowOrWide()` returns either the first (`char const*`) or the second (`wchar_t const*`) argument, depending on template parameter `CharT`.

The macro `NARROW_OR_WIDE` is used to avoid having to write both the narrow and the wide string literal. The macro `TOWSTRING` simply prepends the `L` prefix to the given string literal.

Of course the macro will only work if the range of characters is limited to basic ASCII, but this is usually sufficient. Otherwise one can use the `NarrowOrWide()` template function to define narrow and wide string literals separately.

**Notes:**

I would add a "unique" prefix to the macro names, something like the name of your library, to avoid conflicts with similar macros defined elsewhere.

---

### Method 3 - array initialized via template parameter pack (C++17)

C++17 finally allows us to get rid of the macro and use a pure C++ solution. The solution uses [template parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) expansion to initialize an array from a string literal while `static_cast`ing the individual characters to the desired type.

First we declare a `str_array` class, which is similar to [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) but tailored for constant null-terminated string (e. g. `str_array::size()` returns number of characters without `'\0'`, instead of buffer size). This wrapper class is necessary, because a plain array cannot be returned from a function. It must be wrapped in a struct or class.

```
template< typename CharT, std::size_t Length >
struct str_array
{
    constexpr CharT const* c_str()              const { return data_; }
    constexpr CharT const* data()               const { return data_; }
    constexpr CharT operator[]( std::size_t i ) const { return data_[ i ]; }
    constexpr CharT const* begin()              const { return data_; }
    constexpr CharT const* end()                const { return data_ + Length; }
    constexpr std::size_t size()                const { return Length; }
    // TODO: add more members of std::basic_string

    CharT data_[ Length + 1 ];  // +1 for null-terminator
};
```

So far, nothing special. The real trickery is done by the following `str_array_cast()` function, which initializes the `str_array` from a string literal while `static_cast`ing the individual characters to the desired type:

```
#include <utility>

namespace detail {
    template< typename ResT, typename SrcT >
    constexpr ResT static_cast_ascii( SrcT x )
    {
        if( !( x >= 0 && x <= 127 ) )
            throw std::out_of_range( "Character value must be in basic ASCII range (0..127)" );
        return static_cast<ResT>( x );
    }
    
    template< typename ResElemT, typename SrcElemT, std::size_t N, std::size_t... I >
    constexpr str_array< ResElemT, N - 1 > do_str_array_cast( const SrcElemT(&a)[N], std::index_sequence<I...> )
    {
        return { static_cast_ascii<ResElemT>( a[I] )..., 0 };
    }
} //namespace detail

template< typename ResElemT, typename SrcElemT, std::size_t N, typename Indices = std::make_index_sequence< N - 1 > >
constexpr str_array< ResElemT, N - 1 > str_array_cast( const SrcElemT(&a)[N] )
{
    return detail::do_str_array_cast< ResElemT >( a, Indices{} );
}
```

The [template parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) expansion trickery is required, because constant arrays can only be initialized via aggregate initialization (e. g. `const str_array<char,3> = {'a','b','c',0};`), so we have to "convert" the string literal to such an initializer list.

The code triggers a compile time error if any character is outside of basic ASCII range (0..127), for the reasons given at the beginning of this answer. There are code pages where 0..127 doesn't map to ASCII, so this check does not give 100% safety though.

**Usage:**

```
template< typename CharT >
struct StringTraits
{
    static constexpr auto WHITESPACE_STR = str_array_cast<CharT>( "abc" );
    
    // Fails to compile (as intended), because characters are not basic ASCII.
    //static constexpr auto WHITESPACE_STR1 = str_array_cast<CharT>( "äöü" );
};
```

[**Live Demo at Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bda5fa86db31616a)

Comment: Is there a reason using TOWSTRING rather than TOWSTRING1 directly?

Comment: @user1633272 Macro expansion. When the argument for `TOWSTRING` is a macro, it wouldn't compile. E. g. `#define SOMESTR "abc"` ... `TOWSTRING(SOMESTR)`. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5256500/7571258).

Comment: @user1633272 Actually we could call `TOWSTRING1` directly, because macro expansion already happens in the body of the `NARROW_OR_WIDE` macro. But I like to keep things general, to allow `TOWSTRING` also be used in other contexts.

Comment: Might be worth noting that methods 1 and 3 assume a conversion from any valid `char` to `wchar_t` results in the same character.  This might be the case, but the relationships between a `char` or `wchar_t` value and a conceptual character depend on encoding/locale.

Comment: @aschepler I have made the note, that characters should be restricted to basic ASCII, more prominent now.

Comment: @aschepler For method 3, I have added a compile-time check whether characters  are in basic ASCII range.

Comment: @zett42, can you explain how raising a runtime_error causes a compile time error? Is it because it ceases being a constexpr if the condition is true? Would a static assert have sufficed there?

Comment: @cppguy `static_assert` doesn't work for `constexpr` function arguments, because a `constexpr` function can be called at runtime. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8626055/7571258). And yes, when throwing in `constexpr` function, it ceases to be `constexpr`, but compiler evaluates the branch only if necessary, so it works when the condition evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Here is a refinement of Method 2 that retains the array[count] type of the result, so the result can be used in sizeof() just like the original string literal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63888331/1046167

Comment: No one really tried this, `CharType[] WHITESPACE_STR`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69662759/is-there-any-way-to-switch-the-parameter-default-value-between-char-and-wchar-t

Answer (score 5):

Here is a refinement of the now-common template-based solution which

- **preserves the `array[len]` C++ type of the C strings** rather than decaying them to pointers, which means **you can call sizeof() on the result** and get the size of the string+NUL, not the size of a pointer, just as if you had the original string there.
- Works even if the strings in different encodings have different length in code units (which is virtually guaranteed if the strings have non-ASCII text).
- Does not incur any runtime overhead nor does it attempt/need to do encoding conversion at runtime.

Credit: This refinement starts with the original template idea from [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9040540/1046167) and #2 from [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52738638/1046167) and borrows some ideas from, but fixes the size limitations of, [Chris Kushnir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60770220/1046167).

This code does char and wchar_t but it is trivial to extend it to char8_t+char16_t+char32_t

```
// generic utility for C++ pre-processor concatenation
// - avoids a pre-processor issue if x and y have macros inside
#define _CPP_CONCAT(x, y) x ## y
#define  CPP_CONCAT(x, y) _CPP_CONCAT(x, y)

// now onto stringlit()

template<size_t SZ0, size_t SZ1>
constexpr
auto  _stringlit(char c,
                 const char     (&s0)  [SZ0],
                 const wchar_t  (&s1)  [SZ1]) -> const char(&)[SZ0] 
{
    return s0;
}

template<size_t SZ0, size_t SZ1>
constexpr
auto  _stringlit(wchar_t c,
                 const char     (&s0)  [SZ0],
                 const wchar_t  (&s1)  [SZ1]) -> const wchar_t(&)[SZ1] 
{
    return s1;
}

#define stringlit(code_unit, lit) \
    _stringlit(code_unit (), lit, CPP_CONCAT(L, lit))
```

Here we are not using C++ overloading but rather defining one function per char encoding, each function with different signatures.  Each function returns the original array type with the original bounds.  The selector that chooses the appropriate function is a single character in the desired encoding (value of that character not important).  We cannot use the type itself in a template parameter to select because then we'd be overloading and have conflicting return types.  This code also works without the `constexpr`.  Note we are returning a reference to an array (which is possible in C++) not an array (which is not allowed in C++).  The use of trailing return type syntax here is optional, but a heck of a lot more readable than the alternative, something like `const char (&stringlit(...params here...))[SZ0]` ugh.

I compiled this with clang 9.0.8 and MSVC++ from Visual Studio 2019 16.7 (aka `_MSC_VER` 1927 aka pdb ver 14.27).  I had `c++2a/c++latest` enabled, but I think C++14 or 17 is sufficient for this code.

Enjoy!

Comment: Have updated my LiteralStr code to fix the SIZE problem.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative implementation based on @zett42 's answer. Please advise me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

#define TOWSTRING_(x) L##x
#define TOWSTRING(x) TOWSTRING_(x)  
#define MAKE_LPCTSTR(C, STR) (std::get<const C*>(std::tuple<const char*, const wchar_t*>(STR, TOWSTRING(STR))))

template<typename CharType>
class StringTraits {
public:
    static constexpr const CharType* WHITESPACE_STR = MAKE_LPCTSTR(CharType, "abc");
};

typedef StringTraits<char> AStringTraits;
typedef StringTraits<wchar_t> WStringTraits;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Narrow string literal: " << AStringTraits::WHITESPACE_STR << std::endl;
    std::wcout << "Wide string literal  : " << WStringTraits::WHITESPACE_STR << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great idea to use `std::tuple`. I would propably just choose another name for the macro `DEFINE_LPCTSTR`, because `LPCTSTR` depends on the Unicode project setting, which isn't the case here. So it's a bit confusing.

Comment: @zett42 yes, any suggestion for the naming?

Comment: Maybe `CHARTYPE_STR`? It indicates that the macro uses `CharType` template parameter.

Comment: I'm still wondering, whether a macro-free version is possible. With a `constexpr` function we should in theory be able to do so.

Comment: @zett42 anyway, I think a basic macro is required for declaring both char and wchar_t string, the logic of getting char or wchar_t version of string could be a marco or a function.

Comment: Yesterday evening I would have agreed, but after reading up a bit on template parameter pack expansion today, I finally found a macro-free C++17 solution. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've just came up with a compact answer, which is similar to other C++17 versions. Similarly, it relies on implementation defined behavior, specifically on the environment character types. It supports converting ASCII and ISO-8859-1 to UTF-16 wchar_t, UTF-32 wchar_t, UTF-16 char16_t and UTF-32 char32_t. UTF-8 input is not supported, but more elaborate conversion code is feasible.

```
template <typename Ch, size_t S>
constexpr auto any_string(const char (&literal)[S]) -> const array<Ch, S> {
        array<Ch, S> r = {};

        for (size_t i = 0; i < S; i++)
                r[i] = literal[i];

        return r;
}
```

Full example follows:

```
$ cat any_string.cpp 
#include <array>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

template <typename Ch, size_t S>
constexpr auto any_string(const char (&literal)[S]) -> const array<Ch, S> {
        array<Ch, S> r = {};

        for (size_t i = 0; i < S; i++)
                r[i] = literal[i];

        return r;
}

int main(void)
{
    auto s = any_string<char>("Hello");
    auto ws = any_string<wchar_t>(", ");
    auto s16 = any_string<char16_t>("World");
    auto s32 = any_string<char32_t>("!\n");

    ofstream f("s.txt");
    f << s.data();
    f.close();

    wofstream wf("ws.txt");
    wf << ws.data();
    wf.close();

    basic_ofstream<char16_t> f16("s16.txt");
    f16 << s16.data();
    f16.close();

    basic_ofstream<char32_t> f32("s32.txt");
    f32 << s32.data();
    f32.close();

    return 0;
}
$ c++ -o any_string any_string.cpp -std=c++17
$ ./any_string 
$ cat s.txt ws.txt s16.txt s32.txt 
Hello, World!
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation of zett42 Method 2 above.
Has the advantage of supporting all char types (for literals that can be represented as char[]) and preserving the proper string literal array type.

First the template functions:

```
template<typename CHAR_T>
constexpr
auto  LiteralChar(
    char     A,
    wchar_t  W,
    char8_t  U8,
    char16_t U16,
    char32_t U32
)   -> CHAR_T
{
         if constexpr( std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, char> )      return A;
    else if constexpr( std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, wchar_t> )   return W;
    else if constexpr( std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, char8_t> )   return U8;
    else if constexpr( std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, char16_t> )  return U16;
    else if constexpr( std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, char32_t> )  return U32;
}

template<typename CHAR_T, size_t SIZE>
constexpr
auto  LiteralStr(
    const char     (&A)  [SIZE],
    const wchar_t  (&W)  [SIZE],
    const char8_t  (&U8) [SIZE],
    const char16_t (&U16)[SIZE],
    const char32_t (&U32)[SIZE]
)   -> const CHAR_T(&)[SIZE]
{
         if constexpr( std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, char> )      return A;
    else if constexpr( std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, wchar_t> )   return W;
    else if constexpr( std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, char8_t> )   return U8;
    else if constexpr( std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, char16_t> )  return U16;
    else if constexpr( std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, char32_t> )  return U32;
}
```

Then the macros:

```
#define  CMK_LC(CHAR_T, LITERAL) \
LiteralChar<CHAR_T>( LITERAL, L ## LITERAL, u8 ## LITERAL, u ## LITERAL, U ## LITERAL )

#define  CMK_LS(CHAR_T, LITERAL) \
LiteralStr<CHAR_T>( LITERAL, L ## LITERAL, u8 ## LITERAL, u ## LITERAL, U ## LITERAL )
```

Then use:

```
template<typename CHAR_T>
class StringTraits {
public:
    struct  LC {  // literal character
        static  constexpr CHAR_T  Null  = CMK_LC(CHAR_T, '\0');
        static  constexpr CHAR_T  Space = CMK_LC(CHAR_T, ' ');
    };
    struct  LS {  // literal string
        // can't seem to avoid having to specify the size
        static  constexpr CHAR_T  Space    [2] = CMK_LS(CHAR_T, " ");
        static  constexpr CHAR_T  Ellipsis [4] = CMK_LS(CHAR_T, "...");
    };
};

auto   char_space { StringTraits<char>::LC::Space }; 
auto  wchar_space { StringTraits<wchar_t>::LC::Space };

auto   char_ellipsis { StringTraits<char>::LS::Ellipsis };     // note: const char*
auto  wchar_ellipsis { StringTraits<wchar_t>::LS::Ellipsis };  // note: const wchar_t*

auto  (& char_space_array) [4] { StringTraits<char>::LS::Ellipsis };
auto  (&wchar_space_array) [4] { StringTraits<wchar_t>::LS::Ellipsis };

? syntax to get a local copy ?
```

<strike>Admittedly, the syntax to preserve the string literal array type is a bit of a burden, but not overly so.
Again, only works for literals that have the same # of code units in all char type representations.
If you want LiteralStr to support all literals for all types  would likely need to pass pointers as param and return CHAR_T* instead of CHAR_T(&)[SIZE].  Don't think can get LiteralChar to support multibyte char.</strike>

[EDIT]

Applying Louis Semprini SIZE support to LiteralStr gives:

```
template<typename CHAR_T, 
    size_t SIZE_A, size_t SIZE_W, size_t SIZE_U8, size_t SIZE_U16, size_t SIZE_U32,
    size_t SIZE_R =
        std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, char>     ? SIZE_A   :
        std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, wchar_t>  ? SIZE_W   :
        std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, char8_t>  ? SIZE_U8  :
        std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, char16_t> ? SIZE_U16 :
        std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, char32_t> ? SIZE_U32 : 0
>
constexpr
auto  LiteralStr(
    const char     (&A)   [SIZE_A],
    const wchar_t  (&W)   [SIZE_W],
    const char8_t  (&U8)  [SIZE_U8],
    const char16_t (&U16) [SIZE_U16],
    const char32_t (&U32) [SIZE_U32]
)   -> const CHAR_T(&)[SIZE_R]
{
         if constexpr( std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, char> )      return A;
    else if constexpr( std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, wchar_t> )   return W;
    else if constexpr( std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, char8_t> )   return U8;
    else if constexpr( std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, char16_t> )  return U16;
    else if constexpr( std::is_same_v<CHAR_T, char32_t> )  return U32;
}
```

It is also possible to use a simpler syntax to create variables;
for example, in StringTraits::LS can change to constexpr auto &
so

```
static  constexpr CHAR_T  Ellipsis [4] = CMK_LS(CHAR_T, "...");
```

becomes

```
static  constexpr auto & Ellipsis { CMK_LS(CHAR_T, "...") };
```

When using CMK_LS(char, "literal") any invalid char in literal are converted to '?' by VS 2019, not sure what other compilers do.

Comment: Here is a refinement of your idea that solves the SIZE problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63888331/1046167